# Do I have to download an image before upload it to s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I have Rails app with embedded images. What I want is to upload these images to s3 and serve theme from there instead of form original source Do I have to download the img to my server before upload it to s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: If you're scraping someone's content, then...yes, you need to pull the file down before uploading to to S3.

Long answer: If the other site (the original source) is working with you, you can give them a Presigned URL that they can use to upload to your S3 bucket.

From Amazon's docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html

```
#Uploading an object using a presigned URL for SDK for Ruby - Version 3.

require 'aws-sdk-s3'
require 'net/http'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2')

obj = s3.bucket('BucketName').object('KeyName')
# Replace BucketName with the name of your bucket.
# Replace KeyName with the name of the object you are creating or replacing.

url = URI.parse(obj.presigned_url(:put))

body = "Hello World!"
# This is the contents of your object. In this case, it's a simple string.

Net::HTTP.start(url.host) do |http|
  http.send_request("PUT", url.request_uri, body, {
# This is required, or Net::HTTP will add a default unsigned content-type.
    "content-type" => "",
  })
end

puts obj.get.body.read
# This will print out the contents of your object to the terminal window.
```